# Dynamic where Clause in SQL

Tags: t-sql

I would like to be able to alter a where clause in a Stored Procedure based upon the value of a parameter passed to it.

E.G.

This is how I think it should work but I cannot get it quite right

```
Declare @param as int

set @param = 1

Select Productname
from product
where
 case @param = 1 then productname = 1
 else productname <> 1
 end
```

I have been looking at Dynamic SQL etc?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this WHERE clause:

```
WHERE (@param = 1 AND productname = 1)
OR    (@param <> 1 AND productname <> 1)
```

The parentheses are not strictly needed here because `AND` has higher precedence than `OR` but I've added them anyway for clarity.

Comment: This works, must be my brain this morning but I am struggling to see exactly why! Boolean Logic I am guessing, need to re-fresh my knowledge. Thanks Mark

Comment: @DavidA: This is [logical equality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equality) for you, expressed through conjunction and disjunction: (`a EQ b` -> `(a AND b) OR (NOT a AND NOT b)`). The closest to the actual `EQ` operator I could get in Transact-SQL is this non-[sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) expression: `WHERE CASE productname WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = CASE @param WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`.